# How to Display Dynamic Columns in pentaho reporting?

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

Am new to pentaho reporting.
My requirement was, i have 20 fields, in those 20 fields user can give any fields by choosing their own sothat it populates that columns into report

Example:

### Columns Names:

A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H ..............till Z

Requirement:
User can pick any of the columns above need to be shown in the report with column Header and Relevant  data to particular Column

Result :
A | C | P| W| Y| E------------------>Column Names

1|22| 3| 4| 10| 22 --------------->Relavent Data

which need to be change Dynamically

Please give me Your inputs
1)Please give me the solution through Pentaho Report Designer
2)Pentaho BA SERVER

Thanks,
Poorna Sekhar

Comment: Too bad there is no joy for this older question.  Anybody??